# Complex Lie group $\mathbb{C}^* $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, complex-numbers, lie-groups

How is look group $$ GL(1,\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}^* $$ It takes value in the form $ a + bi $, where  $ a,b \neq 0 $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The notation $\mathbb{C}^*$ means the set of non-zero complex numbers. In other words, it's the set of complex numbers with a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: it is Yes. because $GL(1,\Bbb C)$ are matrices $1\times 1$ and invertibles

Comment: @janmarqz Indeed. And $(1+0\times i)$ is invertible, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for your answer